# Confusion with the definition of the operator norm

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, normed-spaces, definition

In my functional analysis course I have been told the definition of the operator norm is as follows:

$$||T||=\sup\{||Tx||_Y:x\in X,||x||_X\leq1\}$$

I don't understand the relevance of $||x||_X\leq 1$, could someone please explain?

Comment: By linearity, $\|Tx\|_Y$ can be made arbitrarily large by taking $x=\lambda x_0$ for a fixed vector $x_0\in X$ and a scalar $\lambda$ s.t. $\lambda\to+\infty$.

Comment: Sometimes the condition $\|x\|_X=1$ is used in the supremum. This has the drawback that one needs to consider the trivial case $X=\{0\}$ extra. Using the condition $\|x\|_X\le 1$ avoids the need to discuss the special case.

Comment: Consider the operator $T:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ defined by $Tx=x$. (Take the usual modulus as norm on both $\Bbb R$.) Can you get rid of the condition with questioned relevancy?